# Discover Mouse Position Relative to Restored Browser Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, coordinates, mousemove

How do I discover the mouse position relative to the viewable browser window?  If you see screenshot below, I want to determine the co-ordinates of the mouse relative to the viewable area in the browser window whilst hovering over those four thumbnails.  As you can see I consider the top left corner of the viewable area as 0, 0.  I want the exact mouse position and not the position of the thumbnails and I want to achieve cross-browser compatibility.

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img.thumbnails").mousemove(function (event) {
        //X relative to viewable area
        var X = (event.pageX - $(window).scrollLeft());

        //Y relative to viewable area
        var Y = (event.pageY - $(window).scrollTop());
    });
});
```

Thanks!